# Pandas histogram bins

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Coming from other reporting layers I have to apologise for what is probably a stupid question. I have a dataframe that looks like so:

[image]

I am attempting to create a histogram for Total Household Income. The data type for the column is int and all rows contain a value. The dataframe has about 40000 rows and the range of the values are roughly what can be seen in the screenshot.

I then run this command:

`df.hist(column='Total Household Income', bins=10)`

The result is this:

[image]

The bins are weird though. I then created a test data frame with just the values that can be seen in the screenshot above. It has the same data type.

```
my_dict = {'Total Household Income' :[480332, 189235, 82785, 107589, 189322]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

If I then run `df2.hist(column='Total Household Income', bins=10)` the result looks a lot better.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the maximum and minimum range of 'Total Household Income' in your original dataframe? Your x-axis in the first plot is scaled by 1e7, so if you have some very few entries this large (but the majority far lower), the your plot is indeed what you would expect.

Comment: suppose your data has outliers, try to filter them

Comment: If I manually set the values of the bins, then it works